# Show definition of \NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: environments, xparse, debugging

`xparse` provides `\GetDocumentEnvironmentArgSpec` to examine the argument specification of a defined environment (and similarly for commands and showing on the terminal).

However, I would like to be able to also got the *code* that is executed at the beginning and end of the corresponding environment.

For a `\NewDocumentCommand`, one can have a look at `<command name> ~ code`, and similarly there is also the control sequence `environment ~ <envname> ~ code`, but this has some xparse internal stuff at the beginning of it.

**Is there some way to show and/or get just the user given definition of the environment that has been declared?**

I also don't know where the code executed at the end of the environment is stored internally.

Comment: For environment `foo` use `\ShowCommand\foo`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik For me this only gives the `__xparse_start_env:nnnnn ` internal macro, .i.e the regular expansion

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler Could you give details of your LaTeX format and `xparse` version?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik We likely want `\ShowEnviornment` to cover this case

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler Then you need to update.  Support for `xparse` was only added for the 2021-11-15 release.

Comment: @JosephWright I use `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.11.29)` and xparse version `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4 L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
`

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, and something for copying.  Misusing `\ShowCommand` is weird

Comment: Thanks, I will update my TexLive distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PhelypeOleinik and JosephWright pointed out in the comments, the `\ShowCommand` macro does exactly that.

It is available in `xparse` since `2021-11-15`.

In my case, I just needed to update to the 2021 TexLive distribution.

Comment: Actually, `\ShowCommand` is _not_ available in `xparse`:  It's available in the LaTeX kernel, so you don't need to load `xparse` to use it.  Also, most of `xparse` is now part of the kernel (renamed to `ltcmd`), so you most of the time don't need to load `xparse` at all

Comment: Oh, I see. Where is the `\ShowCommand` macro documented? It does not seem to be in `interface3` and also `texdoc kernel` does not give me its documentation

Comment: Its implementation is documented in `texdoc source2e`.  There is still no user documentation ([I am to write one](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/736))

Comment: Alright, that explains it. So I'm happily waiting! :)

Comment: I expect to write that for the June release.  But there won't be much to it:  `\ShowCommand\command` does the best it can to show a meaningful definition of `\command` (if `\command` is defined with `\newcommand`, `\DeclareRobustCommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand`, or `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`), otherwise it does TeX's primitive `\show`